# When I run `./command.sh &`, the background task is suspended. How can I keep it running?

Tags: bash, background-process, job-control

This is what I'm running:

```
alexandma@ALEXANDMA-1-MBP ./command.sh &
[2] 30374
alexandma@ALEXANDMA-1-MBP
[2]  + suspended (tty output)  ./command.sh
```

I don't want it to start suspended, I want it to keep running in the background. I'm going to be running a bunch of these in a loop, so I need something that will work that way.

How can I keep it running?

Comment: you can use cron , it you wan to run after some interval

Comment: I assume you mean cron. How would that be implemented to solve this problem?

Comment: I've explained once here how to use screen for the job: http://serverfault.com/questions/466129/restore-ssh-session/466136#466136

Comment: If you don't care about the `stdout` and `stderr` you can just redirect them to `/dev/null` like `./cmd.sh &> /dev/null &`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It stops because of the reason given: it tries to output to tty. You can try to redirect the output if `./command.sh` supports that, or run the command in a `tmux` or `screen` window of it's own. E.g.

```
 tmux new-window -n "window name" ./command.sh
```

and then view the list of windows created with `tmux list-windows` and attach to `tmux` with `tmux attach`.

That way the program will still wait for input/output to happen, but you can easily provide input once you go to the appropriate window and the output will just be captured without any activity.

Comment: Don't forget `nohup`

Comment: When using `tmux` that is not necessary

Comment: You answered my question with "It stops because of the reason given: it tries to output to tty. You can try to redirect the output if ./command.sh supports that"

Comment: @MattAlexander your comment seems incomplete

Answer (score 15):

Adding a detail to Anthon's explanation:

It is not always the case that a writing background process is stopped. This depends on the terminal setting `tostop`.

```
stty tostop
stty -tostop
```

can be used to toggle this setting. So if you want a background process to write to "another process's" terminal then you can keep it running but don't need `tmux`, `screen` or similar.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do this would be to execute the command as follows:

```
 nohup ./command.sh </dev/null &
```

I include the nohup in the event you are using a SH varient (not CSH varient) and would be terminating your session.

Comment: This works in Zsh, unlike the [`stty` solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166486/54675).

Comment: @Melebius Can you explain why `stty` doesn't work in `zsh`?

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately not. I don’t know anything more about the relations between `stty` and the shell. I just tried these two solutions and `nohup` worked for me.

Comment: @Melebius Maybe related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343088/what-is-the-equivalent-of-stty-echo-for-zsh

Answer (score 2):

Install `screen`.

Once you've installed screen.
Run it :
`# screen`
(you'll have a welcome screen when you first start it)
Run your command : `command.sh`

The press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and then <kbd>d</kbd>.

It's gonna detach the screen launched on the server and keep your command running.

In order to go back to this screen, type :

`screen -r`

Answer (score 1):

You might get this error if your shell is zsh and the script is calling `sudo` and you don't have valid cached credentials (you did not run sudo before, or the previous credentials expired) or `su` and you have to input a password.

If you don't need to keep the output like other answers have mentioned (like running your script without `&` in tmux or screen), here are some possible solutions for this:

- disable the `tty_tickets` or set the `timestamp_type` to `global` in your sudoers file (so that you don't have to enter your password in all the terminals) and/or increase the value of `timestamp_timeout` (this has some serious security implications).
- run a simple command with `sudo` before running the script so that sudo will have cached credentials when encountered in your script.
- change your script so it does not call sudo or su.

Comment: What works fine in bash inside an alias doesn't work in zsh. I just want openvpn to keep running and in bash I did it with alias ovp='sudo openvpn myconfig &'. Can't find a way to make the same work in zsh.

Comment: But you are right saying that this has to do with sudo and cached creds.