# What is the equivalent of "stty -echo" for zsh?

Tags: zsh, stty

I can hide what is written in a terminal with bash with

```
stty -echo
```

This is however not working for zsh: running this command does not change the output of

```
stty -a
```

**What is the equivalent command of `stty -echo` for zsh?**

Comment: N.B. Bash has its own policy for stty. See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/346078/190880).

Comment: Some use cases: reading in passwords, direction controls for a game written in bash.

Answer (score 5):

I think `zsh` resets the terminal when returning to the prompt. Which is actually really useful since it prevents you from getting stuck in the prompt with a broken terminal and having to cast strange incantations to restore sanity.

According to a [mailing list discussion](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2014/msg00870.html), you can make it not do that at the expense of disabling line editing completely with `unsetopt ZLE`.

Answer (score 4):

By default, the terminal configuration associated with the current session is frozen, so most settings done with `stty` are ephemeral.

According to zsh documentation, you can unfroze your terminal with this command

```
ttyctl -u
```

and revert to the regular, frozen mode with:

```
ttyctl -f
```

In unfrozen mode,  your `stty` settings are supposed to persist. It doesn't seems to be the case with `-echo` though.

However, if your goal is to temporarily disable echoing characters for a single command or an external program, the default behavior might be sufficient:

```
$ stty -echo;stty -a;read foo
speed 38400 baud; rows 44; columns 165; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt -echoctl -echoke
$ echo $foo
abc
```

Note that `stty` reports the `-echo` setting and the characters typed in reply to the `read` command weren't echo'ed to the screen.