# The effect of `stty --file=<terminal> <flag>` is only temporary for consoles in bash. Why?

Tags: bash, tty, stty

Open two consoles / X terminals. From one, which is attached to say `/dev/tty1` (Linux console) or `/dev/pts/0` (X terminal), run `$ stty -echo`. (Now echoing to keyboad is turned off.) Then from the other, run `$ stty --file=/dev/tty1 echo`.

Now type something in the first terminal.  It echoes, ok, the last `stty` took effect. But once you press the enter key, It reverts to `-echo` state. Why is this? Is a permanent change possible?

This does not apply to some combinations of stty flags, at least not for 'echo / -echo'. When `$ stty --file= ' is run from the same terminal, it affects permanently.

N.B. Zsh has its own policy for stty. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/343088/190880)

EDIT: In the first post, I failed to report that this happens in bash, but not in dash. The mention to zsh case was also added.

Comment: Your shell is probably do that - resetting terminal modes to allow you to edit command-lines.  With more information, this would be a duplicate.

Comment: Oops, sorry, as you said, it only happens in bash, not in dash. But I can't locate the culprit. Nowhere in the files read at bash startup, there's no `stty` invocation. PS1 does not matter, right? Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell does this, to help you edit command-lines.

bash's readline library saves/restores terminal modes.   You can see this in the [**`rl_prep_terminal`**](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/rltty.c#n601) and [**`rl_deprep_terminal`**](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/rltty.c#n685) functions, called indirectly from [**`edit_and_execute_command`**](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/bashline.c#n944).

Comment: Thanks. So it's specific to bash. For the record: it's done in `bashline.c`.

Comment: well yes - the last link points there, but the function-name seemed more useful.