# `crontab -e` "ruins" terminal

Tags: cron, ncurses

After running `crontab -e`, My terminal starts acting strange, where characters aren't printed in the correct position. Starting and exiting an `ncurses` application (like vim and nano) doesn't help, nor does `reset` fix it either, so I have to restart my terminal emulator.

It appears to have the same symptoms as force quitting an ncurses application.

How do I fix this problem?

**Edit:** Screenshot:
[image]

**Environment**

- I my `$TERM` variable is set to `xterm`
- I use `uxterm` as my emulator
- `crontab` uses `vim` as its editor.

**Edit:** On the first answer, I noticed that it still persists with `xonsh`, even though *it gets fixed when I type `reset` with bash or zsh. So, **it must be some issue with `xonsh`.**

Comment: The basic answer is to run `reset`, but that doesn't fix the underlying problem. What's the value of `$TERM`, and which terminal are you using?

Comment: My `$TERM` variable is **xterm**, and I use `uxterm`.

Comment: If they aren't printed in the correct position, _where are_ they printed?  Please provide a concrete and complete description of what is actually happening.

Comment: @JdeBP I'll do better: I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

OP didn't respond to the comment about `reset`, which should work.  The screenshot shows what happens if I run `bash`, and type

```
stty -onlcr
```

making newlines no longer force a carriage return, just becoming line feeds to produce the staircase effect.

Reconstructing:

[image: breaking and not fixing...]

and running reset:

[image: reset fixes it]

While [bash will reset *some* of the terminal modes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346078/the-effect-of-stty-file-terminal-flag-is-only-temporary-for-consoles-in/346124#346124), between commands, it seems to overlook this one.  The [`reset` manual page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tset.1.html#h3-reset---reinitialization) says it does several things including

> turns on newline translation

Comment: I didn't reply to your answer because I already said in the question that `reset` does not work. However, copying your commands word-for-word, I noticed that `reset` works for bash and zsh, but not for `xonsh`. I'll change my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when starting some java application with `sudo` on the background.

```
sudo /path/to/app &
```

I had to remove the `sudo` so the terminal won't be ruined (and `chown` my app)